# WMI: Querying a specific instance of a class

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, uwf, uwfmgr

I want to make changes to the config of Microsoft Windows UWF Filter (`uwfmgr.exe`) via WMI in C#.
Now certain changes can only be done to a specific instance of the WMI class due to their nature.
For example:

```
    var scope = new ManagementScope(@"root\standardcimv2\embedded");
    using (var uwfClass = new ManagementClass(scope.Path.Path, "UWF_Servicing", null))
    {
        var instances = uwfClass.GetInstances();
        foreach (var instance in instances)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(instance.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This code prints:

```
\\COMPUTER\root\standardcimv2\embedded:UWF_Servicing.CurrentSession=true
\\COMPUTER\root\standardcimv2\embedded:UWF_Servicing.CurrentSession=false
```

The changes can only be done to the instance where CurrentSession = false.

How can I get this instance in a clean way?

In other words, I dont want to do:

```
instance.ToString().Contains("CurrentSession=false")
```

I believe there is a "nicer" way to do this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried something like `foreach (ManagementObject mo in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM UWF_Servicing WHERE CurrentSession = false").Get())`

Comment: @SimonMourier that does work if you provide also the scope path. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SQL for WMI WHERE clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/where-clause) queries, something like this:

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                   @"ROOT\StandardCimv2\embedded",
                   @"SELECT * FROM UWF_Servicing WHERE CurrentSession = FALSE");
foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
{
    ... etc ...
}
```

But you can also use the object's properties (values types will map to standard .NET's types), like this:

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                   @"ROOT\StandardCimv2\embedded",
                   @"SELECT * FROM UWF_Servicing");
foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
{
    var currentSession = obj.GetPropertyValue("CurrentSession");
    if (false.Equals(currentSession))
    {
        ... etc ...
    }
}
```